# Where can I see the name passed in to -[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:]?

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch

In iOS 7, a new variant of `-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]` was introduced that takes a name to *help with debugging*. The new method, `-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:]`, has the following documentation for the name parameter:

> The name to display in the debugger when viewing the background task.

Where/how would one get this name to to be displayed in the debugger?

Comment: Have you looked at the stack trace?  I think it shows there (not sure enough to provide an answer however)